# IIS 7.0 Deployment issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

We have Successfully migrated to Moss to SharePoint 2010 .Now our Current System Configuration is :
system Type : 64 bit ,
OS : Windows Server 2008 R2 , 
Database : SQL SERVER 2008 R2 ,
IIS 7.0 , 
Sharepoint 2010 Server.

I am Having Some Asp.net web application which is already in Windows server 2003 - 32 bit System . I am Having Code of all Web Applications  .

I want to Deploy  all Asp.net web Applications to IIS 7.0 .

I Used below Reference for Deployment .But I didn't get any Success .

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/383492/Configuring-IIS-7-for-ASP-NET-Applications-Deploym

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0

http://gilbertadjin.wordpress.com/2009/10/10/deploying-asp-net-apps-using-iis-7/

Errors :
1. The website declined to show this webpage
2. Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage -- It is not Redirected to particular page and folder .

please suggest some solutions .

Comment: Please add some useful information to have help: what kind of error do you have? 500? 404? What did you find inside log?

Comment: 404 Error ,, and In the code I have given relative Path Its Front Page Is opening properly But Other Page When I click on the menu It is giving Error : Page Can not be Found .

Answer (score 0):

Is ASP.NET installed?
did you run `aspnet_regiis  -i` ?
Is Application Pool running on the desired ASP.NET version?
**is ASP.NET enabled in IIS\ISAPI and CGI Restrictions?** (this causes a 404 error)

Answer (score 0):

check Apppool. sometimes it will fix the issue